# How to use custom check in checkStyle from eclipse : without maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I am trying to write custom check and use it from Eclipse.

I have wrote one MethodLimitCheck.java and one myChecker.xml file for that.

---

java file : `MethodLimitCheck.java`

```
package myCheck;

import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.*;

public class MethodLimitCheck extends Check
{
    private static final int DEFAULT_MAX = 10;
    private int max = DEFAULT_MAX;

    public void setMax(int limit)
    {
        max = limit;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] getDefaultTokens()
    {
        return new int[]{TokenTypes.CLASS_DEF, TokenTypes.INTERFACE_DEF};
    }

    @Override
    public void visitToken(DetailAST ast)
    {
        DetailAST objBlock = ast.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.OBJBLOCK);

        int methodDefs = objBlock.getChildCount(TokenTypes.METHOD_DEF);

        if (methodDefs > this.max) 
        {
            log(ast.getLineNo(),
                    "too many methods, only " + this.max + " are allowed");
        }
    }
}
```

---

and xml file : `myChecker.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="myCheckStyle.MethodLimitCheck">
      <property name="max" value="5" />
    </module>
  </module>
</module>
```

---

how can I use this check in eclipse?

I have taken this example from [CheckStyle site](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html). But how to use that in Eclipse?

I need to get the warnings in eclipse like when I use the available checks and form a custom configuration, That can be used from `project->property->checkStyle`.

I am new with this tool, so if I'm missing something basic, please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must basically write your own little Eclipse plugin to do that. When the plugin works, you will see your custom check in the Checkstyle dialog provided by eclipse-cs.

Here's a [tutorial on how to do that](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/extending_custom_checks.html) courtesy of the eclipse-cs documentation. There is also sample code.

Once it's done, the whole thing seems to be simple. But be patient, it may take a whole day to really get the hang of this if you are new to Eclipse plugins.

Answer (score 3):

You need [**eclipse-cs**](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/index.html) plugin. It integrates **checkstyle** to eclipse and allows providing custom checks.
Also, look at [**sevntu.checkstyle**](https://github.com/sevntu-checkstyle/sevntu.checkstyle). It is extension to the **eclipse-cs** plugin. **Sevntu.checkstyle** adds many useful checks and allows to append your own checks(see wiki on github). Maybe it contains check that you need.

Comment: Yes, using sevntu-checkstyle extension you can easily add custom Checkstyle checks to list of available checks of eclipse-cs plugin. It is the easiest and fastest solution. We tested sevntu-checkstyle extension widely by writing our own checks for Checkstyle, integrating them into it and checking huge production code amounts in Eclipse with eclipse-cs plugin + sevntu-checkstyle extension installed.